# Page without extension with disregarded text before

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess allows me to view the page as follows:

```
http://www.test.com/test.php as http://www.test.com/test

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

How it poissible to add anything text before the file name which will be disregarded such as:

```
http://www.test.com/test34566/test or http://www.test.com/anything/test
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a regular expression, your URL would split in to everything *before* the last backslash, and everything after it.

```
^(.*)/([^/]*)/?$
```

This should allow you to ignore everything before ($1) and use everything after ($2).

Beware though if you are using directories such as in your example, you need to use a rewritecondition that also checks to make sure that the requested URL isn't an actual directory, as well as it not being a file.